# Forwarding channel message by incoming webhook to a specific chat in microsoft teams

Tags: chat, microsoft-teams, webhooks, channel, forward

I've configured an incoming webhook and pushes messages into it this way:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), TeamsWebhook_Url))
    {
        request.Content = new StringContent($"{'text':'Application started by {Environment.UserName}'}");
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

That works fine. Now I want the incoming message forwarded to a chat, is that possible? I found hints to do that by an listener, but I need the chat id to use that.

Has anyone an example how to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently its not possible to forward channel message by incoming webhook to a specific chat in Microsoft teams.

You can suggest this feature here:
[Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)

As a workaround using graph Api you can [get the channel message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and then you can [create the chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and [send the message in chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using chat id.